# How to use javascript to display the menu after clicking, and click the blank space or button again to close the menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi everyone~ I just learned javascript recently and want to practice doing a project!
My English is not good, I try to describe my problem completely.

I hope to click the button to open the menu. Click again on the button and the blank space outside the menu to close the menu, but I still don’t know how to judge to complete this project. I would like to ask everyone to help. Thank you.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('.click').getAttribute('class');
let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

// el.onclick = function(){
//   el.getAttribute('class','showmenu')
// }
```

```css
body{
  min-height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.click{
  padding:16px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color:#fff;
  &:hover{
    transition:0.3s;
    background-color: #222;
  }
} 
 .menu{
    position:absolute;
    top:380px;
    left:480px;
    background-color: #71ff05;
    border-radius:4px;
    display: none;
   .menu__item{
     padding:36px;
     text-align:center;
     border-bottom:1px solid #222;
     &:hover{
       background-color: #489b09;
     }
    }
  }

.showmenu{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="click">button</a>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">test1</li>
    <li class="menu__item">test2</li>
    <li class="menu__item">test3</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add event listener to button to open the menu and add event listener on window to close the menu.

```
const el = document.querySelector('.click')
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

el.onclick = function(){
  menu.classList.toggle("showmenu");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.click')) {
    menu.classList.remove('showmenu')
  }
}
```

See my [codepen example](https://codepen.io/jegatheesprana/pen/ZEKmeaq)

**Edit**

As you asked in the comment, if you want to prevent to menu from closing if the users click on menu, use need to add exception on the `window.onClick`

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.click')&&!(event.target.matches('.menu')||event.target.matches('.menu__item'))) {
    menu.classList.remove('showmenu')
  }
}
```

I have update it in the same codepen example as well.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering me as a beginner, but I want to ask if I want to click on the menu, he can not disappear, but the menu will disappear after clicking on the menu. How to rewrite this program?

Comment: @WEIA I've updated my answer. Can you check it please

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and let me learn a lot of JS knowledge, thank you again for your help!
Wish you peace and happiness

Answer (score 1):

You should use `toggle`

```js
let menu =  document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0]
document.getElementsByClassName("click")[0].onclick =function() {
       menu.classList.toggle("showmenu");
      };
```

```css
body{
  min-height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.click{
  padding:16px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-decoration:none;
  border-radius:10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color:#fff;
  &:hover{
    transition:0.3s;
    background-color: #222;
  }
} 
 .menu{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:480px;
    background-color: #71ff05;
    border-radius:4px;
    display: none;
   .menu__item{
     padding:36px;
     text-align:center;
     border-bottom:1px solid #222;
     &:hover{
       background-color: #489b09;
     }
    }
  }

.showmenu{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <button  class="click">button</button>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">test1</li>
    <li class="menu__item">test2</li>
    <li class="menu__item">test3</li>
  </ul>
```